# Prospects going to Sync Queue

Tags: leads, pardot, sync

We have a form handler embedded in a website. The completion action of this form handler is "Assign prospect via Salesforce Active Assignment Rule". When a user fills the form a prospect is created but a lead for that prospect is not created. But when I click on manual sync the lead gets created. So the possible reason I can see is that when the form is submitted the "Assign prospect via Salesforce Active Assignment Rule" does not work but on manual sync Pardot checks that and creates the lead.
Can anybody tell me how to fix this or is there something I missed?
[image]

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000320078&type=1

Comment: When I am creating a prospect manually it is syncing fine, only when using form handler I am facing this even though everything seems fine